# É possível usar exceção em C?

Tags: c, característica-linguagem, exceção

Mesmo que não seja exatamente como um `throw` e `catch`, tem como fazer uso de algo parecido com a exceção em C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível, em certa medida.

A maioria das implementações de mecanismos exceção das linguagens possuem algo muito mais sofisticado e se você quiser isso pode implementar por sua conta até um certo limite, mas não será usado universalmente. É como acontece com *closure*, a parte básica C tem, mas a captura é algo que o programador tem que se virar.

C tem como fazer um `goto` distante de forma pronta, ou seja, que vá além do algoritmo da função que está. Inclusive mecanismos de exceção mais simples usam um mecanismo no mínimo muito parecido. Você precisa do `setjmp.h` incluído no código para pegar as funções da biblioteca padrão para poder usar.

Lá tem uma função que indica onde é o `catch` ([`setjmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/setjmp)) e outra que lança o desvio ([`longjmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/longjmp)).

Só tenha certo que as pessoas não gostam disso e é raro ver em qualquer código. Se o `goto` é considerado ruim, imagina isso.

[Exemplo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

static jmp_buf buf;

void second() {
    printf("second\n");         // prints
    longjmp(buf,1);             // jumps back to where setjmp was called - making setjmp now return 1
}

void first() {
    second();
    printf("first\n");          // does not print
}

int main() {
    if (!setjmp(buf))
        first();                // when executed, setjmp returned 0
    else                        // when longjmp jumps back, setjmp returns 1
        printf("main\n");       // prints
    return 0;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Library/SetJump.c).

Note que o você precisa até declarar onde guardar o controle.

Claro que pode usar algum mecanismo seu para algo mais sofisticado. Algo muito sofisticado não dá porque o compilador não tem suporte, por isso um compilador C++ foi criado, não era possível só converter para C.

Conforme dito em comentário abaixo, é possível usar também a [`signal.h`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling). Não é a mesma coisa, e não é o mesmo mecanismo da exceção, mas é algo mais sofisticado e pode alcançar o mesmo objetivo de forma melhor já que é um sistema de eventos, que não é muito diferente do que uma exceção funciona.

Comment: Entendo que escreveu uma pergunta para a sua própria resposta e isso aqui é normal, mas acho que devia considerar rever a existência de `signal.h` e chamadas a `kill`, `raise` e `signal` porque esse é o mecanismo de exceções em `C`. E depois de rever poderia incrementar sua resposta. `SIGUSR1` e `SIGUSR2` não são assim coisas novas afinal

Comment: Vou colocar alguma coisa. Obrigado.